# Code uploading error on NodeMCU v3 "the selected serial port _ does not exist on your connected board"

Tags: nodemcu

when trying to upload code to NodeMCU v3, sometimes I get the error "*the selected serial port _ does not exist on your connected board*" and sometimes "*timed out waiting for packet header*". My attempts for this problem:

- No cable is connected to any pin,
- I changed the USB port,
- Then I checked the components of the card, everything
  seemed fine.
- I checked the pin headers, there was no bridge.
- Then I cleaned the whole board 4-5 times with 1-minute intervals for the
  possibility of solder paste.

Still, the result did not change, what can I do in this case?

**EDIT**
I opened serial monitor with "74880 baud" and pushed to rst output is,

```
02:49:04.182 -> 
02:49:04.182 ->  ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,7)
02:49:04.228 -> 
02:49:04.228 -> load 0x4010f000, len 3460, room 16 
02:49:04.228 -> tail 4
02:49:04.228 -> chksum 0xcc
02:49:04.228 -> load 0x3fff20b8, len 40, room 4 
02:49:04.228 -> tail 4
02:49:04.228 -> chksum 0xc9
02:49:04.228 -> csum 0xc9
02:49:04.228 -> v00062500
02:49:04.228 -> ~ld
```

Comment: On what OS are you? You might need to install the drivers for the CH340 chip, which does the USB communication.

Comment: I installed and uptaded driver for CH340

Comment: Are you pressing the "boot" button on your NodeMCU during reset, to put it into Flash mode manually before attempting to program it?

Comment: I tried that but result doesnt change